# Javascript scroll: How to execute function only once with least amount of CPU usage?

Tags: javascript, function, scroll

I have a simple website consisting of a single page. Usage behavior is being tracked via Piwik. Due to the design of the page, users usually resort to scrolling through it instead of using the navbar and clicking on links, making link trackinga very uninformative method to get some insight into how the website is being used. To track user behavior, I have a js function using "scroll" that determines the location of the user on the page and then sends a request to the tracking server:

```
setInterval(reportposition, 1000); 
 function reportposition () {
    $(function () {
             var $win = $(window);

             $win.scroll(function () {
                 if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
                     _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Scroll', 'PageTop']);
}               else if (($(document).height() - $win.scrollTop()
                                < 7540) && ($(document).height() - $win.scrollTop() > 7500 )) {
                     _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Scroll', 'About']);
}
                 else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop()
                                == $(document).height()) {
                     _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Scroll', 'PageBottom']);
                 }
             });
         });
};
```

However, every scroll that satisfies one of the conditions does so dozens of times and thus sends dozens of tracking requests to the server. I tried to lower the frequency the function is run with setInterval, but the effect is negligible. Is there any way to get the function to fire off only once when a condition has been met until a different condition is satisfied?

Using scroll to check for the position of the user seems to be rather demanding regarding CPU cycles as sometimes hundreds of events can occur with a simple scroll. Is there any way to solve this problem with as little CPU usage as possible?

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to check if the scrollTop is equal to the scrollTop of the current div the user has scrolled on.

In terms of CPU, look at https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery . This is one solution; more ideally you should look at using Websockets (i.e., using socket.io with node.js).

Answer (score 1):

scroll event is unnecessary in your case, since it is only useful for detecting if the user has scrolled whereas you can check that by only comparing with scrollTop() value of a second ago. You also dont need to access height values if they do not

```
setInterval(reportposition, 1000); 
var $win = $(window);

function reportposition () {
    $(function () {
        if(scrollTop == $win.scrollTop()){
            //same position
        }
        scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();
        winHeight = $win.height();
        docHeight = $(document).height();
        if (scrollTop == 0) {
             _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Scroll', 'PageTop']);
        }else if ((docHeight - scrollTop < 7540) 
            && (docHeight - scrollTop > 7500 )) {
             _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Scroll', 'About']);
        }else if (winHeight + scrollTop
                        == docHeight) {
             _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Scroll', 'PageBottom']);
         }
    });
};
```

Other way around, inside the scroll event, you can check how much time has passed and decide whether to process or not.